# Another custom template tag registration issue in django

Tags: python, django

I know there are similar issues, I tried to learn from them, but still doesn't work. I am trying to register custom template tag in django. I have following error:

```
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Module  order.templatetags.order_tags does not have a variable named 'register'
```

mytemplate.html:

```
{% load order_tags %}
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    "menu",
    "order",
    "page",
    # "user.apps.UserConfig",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "order", 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            "libraries" : {
                "order_tags" : "order.templatetags.order_tags",
            },
        },
    },
]
```

order_tags.py:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def create_var(data):
    return str(data)
```

Structure:

```
order/
    templates/...
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
       order_tags.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    views.py
```

I tried shutting down the server. I also tried adding `"order.templatetags",` in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

I also confirmed that order_tags.py loads without an error:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from order.templatetags import order_tags
```

**+++UPDATE+++**
When I updated settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "order", 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Different traceback occurs:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'order_tags' is not a 

registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

**+++UPDATE 2+++**
I used pdb to check the source of the problem, but unfortunately I do not understand that:

```
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(191)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb)
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(191)_get_module_lock()->_ModuleLock('... 1417680005768
(Pdb)
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(149)__enter__()
(Pdb)
...
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(91)acquire()
(Pdb)
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(92)acquire()
(Pdb)
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(101)acquire()
(Pdb)
KeyError: 1884
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(101)acquire()
(Pdb)
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(101)acquire()->None
(Pdb)
KeyError: 1884
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(149)__enter__()
(Pdb)
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(149)__enter__()->None
(Pdb)
KeyError: 1884
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(980)_find_and_load()
(Pdb)
--Return--
```

Thanks!
Django==2.2.6
Python==3.7.4

Comment: do you have "order" in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @Saturnix this is a really good question, I updated my query. Unfortunately it is there ...

Comment: I am wondering why you add this "libraries" : {
                "order_tags" : "order.templatetags.order_tags",
            }, to the the templates on your settings ? because no where i can find the utility of it

Comment: @FarhaniWalid I took it blindly from [Custom template not loading correctly in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449700/custom-template-not-loading-correctly-in-django). Please check my update. From documentation: >!Alternatively, template tag modules can be registered through the 'libraries' argument to DjangoTemplates. This is useful if you want to use a different label from the template tag module name when loading template tags. It also enables you to register tags without installing an application.

Comment: @Sliwa How are you using the new templatetag inside your template?

Comment: @arthursribeiro I don't use it yet, I didn't have a chance to play with it. I updated traceback to " 'order_tags' is not a registered tag library " - I played with template and I left it with {% load create_var %} for some reason.

Comment: Can that be related to Anaconda on Windows? I use it to toggle between environments.